# PHP and AJAX handing off variables

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to process information on my php page, but for some reason the first JS call doesn't seem to be executing.  I've been looking at this off and on for 6 hours.  Can anyone spot my mistake?

```
<script>
function GetData()
{
    var idNumber=document.getElementById("idNumber").value;
    var CallLetters=document.getElementById("CallLetters").value;
    var AName=document.getElementById("AName").value;
    var CName=document.getElementById("CName").value;
    var Xcoord=document.getElementById("Xcoord").value;
    var Ycoord=document.getElementById("Ycoord").value;
    var Dispos=document.getElementById("Dispos").value;
    var Comments=document.getElementById("Comments").value;
    var Packaged="&id="+idNumber+"&Call="+CallLetters+"&AN="+AName+"&CN="+CName+"&X="+Xcoord+"&Y="+Ycoord+"&Di="+Dispos+"&Comm="+Comments;
    alert(Packaged);
    showK(Packaged,'../AJAX/ajax_lookup_group.php?editSave=1','ALists');
}
</script>

<script>
function showK(strSelect,strDestination,strDIV)
{
    if (strSelect=="")
    {
        document.getElementById(strDIV).innerHTML="";
        return;
    } 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById(strDIV).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
alert(strDestination+strSelect);
xmlhttp.open("GET",strDestination+strSelect,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<form>
<table><tr><td>
    <input type="hidden" name="idNumber" id="idNumber" value="1">
    <input type="text" name="CallLetters" id="CallLetters" size="2" value="TES"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="AName" id="AName" size="12" value="Testers"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="CName" id="CName" size="12" value="TesterBob"></td>
    <td>X:<input type="text" name="Xcoord" id="Xcoord" size="2" value="333"><br>
    Y:<input type="text" name="Ycoord" id="Ycoord" size="2" value="444"></td><td style="text-align:left"><select name="Dispos" id="Dispos">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        </select></td><td><textarea rows="2" cols="30" name="Comments" id="Comments">we are testing</textarea></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="GetData()"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console? Do you see the alerts?

Comment: @Barmar I don't generally use JS that much, so I'm not sure how to look at the JS console.  I'm coding using Coda on a MAC and rendering in Chrome.  I don't see any obvious errors.

Comment: @Barmar  if I manually append the URL called in showK, and append the "Packaged" string, I do get what I'm hoping to get.

Comment: View -> Developer -> Developer Tools to open the Chrome debugger.

Comment: What's the PHP issue here? I only see HTML and Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar the error: "Uncaught TypeError:Cannot set 'innerHTML' of null"

Comment: @Barmar  This whole thing lives in PHP, I didn't know if that effected how the JS would run.  The "ALists" DIV tag works. I've executed the "ShowK" function 4 different times prior to hitting this section of code, and it works as desired the other times.... Not sure if that helps.

Comment: JS doesn't care where the page came from, it's just HTML and Javascript when it gets to the browser. That error means that `document.getElementById('Alists')` isn't finding the `ALists` DIV. I don't see that DIV in the HTML you posted.

Comment: I think I've got it mostly figured out.  The code above is actually on the ajax_lookup_group.php page.  That page is actually a page that was called using AJAX from another parent page.  The "GetData" function actually needs to be on that parent page for it to execute properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is on the ajax_lookup_group.php page. That page is actually a page that was called using AJAX from another parent page. The "GetData" function actually needs to be on that parent page for it to execute properly.